# Using httpClient.sendAsync(...) do not send request if thread terminate too early

Tags: java, http, asynchronous

I'm using java.net.http.HttpClient to send some request and ignore the response but when I tried to test I noticed that the request are not sent if I don't wait a little.

I have a very simple method:

```
public CompletableFuture<HttpResponse<String>> getAsyncHttp(final String url) {
    HttpClient httpClient = HttpClient.newHttpClient();
    HttpRequest request = HttpRequest.newBuilder()
            .uri(URI.create(url))
            .build();
    System.out.println("Send request : " + url);
    return httpClient.sendAsync(request, HttpResponse.BodyHandlers.ofString());
}
```

that I call like so:

```
private static void callRequest(){
    HttpAsyncRequest httpAsyncRequest = new HttpAsyncRequest();
    String URL = "http://localhost:3000/test";
    httpAsyncRequest.getAsyncHttp(URL);
    System.out.println("Request done.");
    // we exit here basically
}
```

I'm just trying to send the http request and ignore the response on purpose but the request is not sent.

However, If change my callRequest() method and add a thread sleep

```
private static void callRequest() throws InterruptedException {
    HttpAsyncRequest httpAsyncRequest = new HttpAsyncRequest();
    String URL = "http://localhost:3000/test";
    httpAsyncRequest.getAsyncHttp(URL);
    Thread.sleep(100); // line added
    System.out.println("Request done.");
    // we exit here basically
}
```

Now the request is sent but it is very weird to need to add a thread sleep when I am not waiting for the server since I'm simply sending the request.

Can people reproduce this issue or care to explain why it happens ?

Thank you.

Comment: Because there's nothing that waits for that async call to complete

Answer (score 1):

The call is asynchronous. This means that it is executing independently of its calling thread.  You don't know that it is 'done' unless and until you get a notification that it is done.

Getting the notification is precisely why the 'sendAsync' call returns a Future.  Wait on the Future in your callRequest method (via 'get', for example), don't just ignore it.

I read that you don't need the response, but the API you've chosen to use gives no way to know that the request has even left the local system, much less arrived in the remote server. Without some sort of response you cannot know if and when the server has seen the request; that is unknowable. (At the TCP level, an ack just means it's got as far as the remote TCP stack). Thus awaiting a response is the only way this can be made reliable.

[Doc for CompleteableFuture](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html)

Comment: I understand what you mean but I know when the call is "done" because I'm sending a request to my own server which logs a line when he get the request.
If I wait for the response with a get(), I need to wait the full time of the response, which might be long and I don't want that.

Comment: "You knowing" means nothing to the client software.  Anyway, you don't need to "wait".  There are  other ways to deal with async operations.  But "issue the request and forget about it" is not one of them.

Comment: If nothing else, replace your 'sleep' by a [get with timeout](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html#get-long-java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit-) on the Future.   Print a good message if it times out, rather than claiming 'request done'.